# Error when calculating route in nokia / ovi / here maps

Tags: javascript, here-api

This one's been driving me crazy for hours.
Nokia maps javascript api is erroring out on me if a routing request fails for any reason.
While testing I have it trying to give me a driving route from the middle of the ocean to some random other coordinates I put in. I've looked into the nokia code as much as I've been able to.

So, obviously, trying to make the route fails and this is the code coming back

```
(function(){nokia.maps.net.Request.callbacks[10](11,arguments);})({"details":"NOROUTE: Request failed","additionalData":[],"type":"ApplicationError","subtype":"NoRouteFound"})
```

That's what gets sent to what I assume is some error handling code in routing-nlp.js

```
qb:function(a){
    var b=a.details;a.additionalData&&(b+=" Key: "+a.additionalData[0].key+", Value: "+a.additionalData[0].value);
    return{type:a.type.charAt(0).toLowerCase()+a.type.substr(1),subtype:a.subtype.charAt(0).toLowerCase()+a.subtype.substr(1),message:b}}});
```

May have got the wrong number of brackets in the copy paste there, but everything else is as it is shown. As you can see, the returned information just has an empty array for the additionalData so it shouldn't be trying to extract anything from it...but it does. And then errors because there is nothing at a.additionalData[0].key (cannot read property 'key' of undefined).

This is all kicked off by:

```
        var router = new nokia.maps.routing.Manager();

        router.addObserver("state", onRouteCalculated);

        var waypoints = new nokia.maps.routing.WaypointParameterList();
        waypoints.addCoordinate(new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(20, 54));
        waypoints.addCoordinate(new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(0.06275, 0.3966));

        var modes = [{
            type: "shortest",
            transportModes: ["car"]
        }];

        router.calculateRoute(waypoints, modes);
```

Using js api from https://js.api.here.com/ee/2.5.3/jsl.js?with=all

EDIT: Answer is that this is currently because of a bug in the response from Enterprise Routing. See comments on the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting an error is because your start point is in the middle of the [Empty Quarter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rub%27_al_Khali) of Saudi Arabia, where there are literally no roads for miles around. The routing api tries but fails to find a **nearby** road to start the route from an sends back an error response.

The [JavaScript API](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/maps) is simply a wrapper around the underlying RESTful [Routing API](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing). If you look at the underlying [response](http://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=20,54&waypoint1=0.06275,0.3966&mode=fastest;car;traffic%3aenabled&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg) you will get the following error:

```
{
    "type":"ApplicationError",
    "subtype":"NoRouteFound",
    "details":"Error is NGEO_ERROR_ROUTE_NO_START_POINT",
    "additionalData":[
        {
            "key":"error_code",
            "value":"NGEO_ERROR_ROUTE_NO_START_POINT"
        }
    ],
    "metaInfo":
    {
        "timestamp":"2013-12-16T11:14:22.991",
        "mapVersion":"8.30.52.113",
        "moduleVersion":"7.2.39.0_CD-793_1",
        "interfaceVersion":"2.4.37"
    }
}
```

This is handled in the JavaScript Wrapper by setting the `state` of the Routing Manager to `"failed"`

Presumably you already have an observer for the `state` attribute in your code, you can extend it to handle the error case as shown:

```
onRouteCalculated = function (observedRouter, key, value) {
        if (value == "finished") {
            var routes = observedRouter.getRoutes();
            var mapRoute = new 
                    nokia.maps.routing.component.RouteResultSet(routes[0]).container;
            map.objects.add(mapRoute);
            map.zoomTo(mapRoute.getBoundingBox(), false, "default");
        } else if (value == "failed") {
            alert("The routing request failed.");
        }
    };
```

The code for a fully working [example](http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-js/routing/map-with-route-from-a-to-b.html) with error handling can be found within the [API Explorer](http://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/api-explorer)

Comment: Well that's what I was saying. I was expecting the routing request to fail, but I never receive that expected (and quite normal) failure state because an actual failure in the code is crashing the javascript. Compare the expected response that you posted with what I actually received while debugging.
Your type, subtype, details, and additionalData fields all have values. I posted the response that I got which is missing any values for 'additionalData'. And so it crashes. It looks to me like I'm getting incomplete response data.

Comment: The request generated from my code looks like this
https://route.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/calculateroute.json?routeattributes=shape&maneuverattributes=direction,shape&jsonAttributes=1&waypoint0=geo!25,54&waypoint1=geo!0.06275,0.3966&language=en-US&mode0=shortest;car;&app_id=WgevZ2m4AF8WHx1TY6GS&app_code=G11AO2dbvCRTdCjfTf-mUw&xnlp=CL_JSMv2.5.3,SID_1E571B54-B7F4-45B2-A6B6-60CB22A07C6C&jsoncallback=(function()%7Bnokia.maps.net.Request.callbacks%5B4%5D(5,arguments);%7D)
As you can see there are no values in additionalData.

Comment: The different response depends upon whether you are using Enterprise Routing 6.2 or Standard Routing 7.2   I plugged in your location into the [example](http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-js/routing/map-with-route-from-a-to-b.html) and it failed gracefully for me. How does that example work for you?

Comment: Aha - it looks like this is an Enterprise Routing bug. Pluging in your values into the [Enterprise API Explorer](http://developer.here.com/enterprise/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-js/routing/map-with-route-from-a-to-b.html) and I am able to get _TypeError: a is undefined_ - the simplest suggested workaround would be to use the standard routing API if possible.